Hypothetical ancestry and evolution of PGmc *auziwandliaz
This is cross-posted from r/asklinguistics, with influence from Wiktionary's Tea Room.
So I'm bundling up three questions regarding the PGmc. proper noun *Auziwandilaz.
First: The /w/ in the descendants of this name are described in the Wiktionary Tea Room entry as follows:

*Auziwandilaz yields forms with -w-, as in ON Aurvandil, Lombardic Auriwandalo, but contrast OE Earendel, OHG Orentil and, perhaps most puzzlingly, Gothic auzandil.

How can this be explained? (The Tea Room entry also asks about PGmc. *Audawakraz, which shows a similar double development.)
Second: Is there any evidence for the first element being a stand-alone word? There's a consensus for it being a descendant of PIE *h₂ews-, but nothing about it in Proto-Germanic besides the name. I've asked around and gotten answers involving cranberry morphemes but not much else.
Third: This last one's on the hypothetical linguistics side of things. I've recently learned of a Mediaeval Latin borrowing descending from the root in question, namely Horiwandilus. How would this borrowing evolve on the path to modern-day Romance? I'd also like to know how English would borrow this descendant form (and if it would displace the native Earendel).

Could you add links to the relevant discussions on Reddit and Wiktionary and some more information about the word? It’s easier to answer what’s going on with the w in descendants if we know what the descendants are… Googling the word yields just one single result for me, which is a (seemingly completely unrelated) Instagram account. Edit: Did you mean *Auziwandilaz instead of *Auziwandiliaz?

haha yea hold up...
reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/asklinguistics/comments/18f7ypr/etymology_thread_post_questions_about_words/
(comments, my user is ThetaCheese9999)
tea room (july 2020):https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Etymology_scriptorium/2020/July#The_mystery_of_the_missing_*-w-:Proto-Germanic*Auziwandilaz,_*Audawakraz
wikitionary pages for auziwandilaz (and audawakraz too for question 1):
https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/Auziwandilaz
https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/Audawakraz

I’ve tidied up the question and added the links (plus some information from the Tea Room) to make it more self-contained. Ultimately, I think there’s a good question here, and I don’t think the downvotes are warranted, but it needed more detail included. I would also suggest getting rid of the third question, which isn’t really on-topic, to keep it focused.

The name attested in the Gesta Danorum is Horwendillus. Where did you find Horiwandilus?

Must've gotten it confused. The link on the Wikitionary page for *Auziwandilaz is Horiwandilus (though it doesn't have a page itself, I'm trying to work on that)
